# How to mix markup for straight apostrophes and accented letters in a lstlisting environment?

Tags: listings, accents, apostrophe

I have a document, formatted with luatex, beginning

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}         %Requires luatex engine to handle UTF-8
                              %Consider using minted, but ...
    ...
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\maketitle
```

that uses the listings package to display code samples of Rexx, a language that uses the ASCII apostrophe as a delimiter. The code samples include a letter e with an accent aigu ("é"), which I enter as "\’{e}", and an ASCII apostrophe ("'"), which I enter as "{\textquotesingle}". This works fine in text

```
For example, the Unicode string {\textquotesingle\}Caf\'{e}{\textquotesingle\} has 4 code points, 4
grapheme clusters and 5 octets in UTF-8 encoding while
{\textquotesingle\}Cafe\textbf{'}{\textquotesingle\} has 5 code points, 4 grapheme clusters and 6 octets
in UTF-8 encoding, yet many text processing applications need to treat
them as equivalent.
```

renders properly as

> For example, the Unicode string 'Café' has 4 code points, 4 grapheme
> clusters and 5 octets in UTF-8 encoding while 'Cafe’' has 5 code
> points, 4 grapheme clusters and 6 octets in UTF-8 encoding, yet many
> text processing applications need to treat them as equivalent.

The apostrophe should be rendered as straight.

The second piece is that

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    foo = 'Ren\'{e}'
    parse upper var foo bar
\end{lstlisting}
```

renders as

> ```
> foo = ’Ren\’{e}’
> ```
>
> ____parse upper var foo bar

where _ is actually the visible space cup. The ' is not interpolated and the leading spaces on the second line are not rendered properly.

I was able to use \'{ } to display a bare accent aigu, and with a recent LaTeX I was able to use \textquotesingle for a straight apostrophe.

MWE for listing:

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}         %Requires luatex engine to handle UTF-8
                              %Consider using minted, but ...

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\begin{lstlisting}
    foo = {\textquotesingle\}Ren\'{e}{\textquotesingle}
    parse upper var foo bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The documentation for listings claims that it is possible to escape to LaTeX, but I have not been able to make that work. The markup I used above, in plain text, renders properly as "’Café’".

So my question is, without entering characters above U+7F, what luatex compatible package and markup should I use for the sample code without affecting the rendering of apostrophe elsewhere in the document? I can give up syntax highlighting as long as the code is indented, not wrapped,  and is boxed or otherwise distinguished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to input accents the old way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

% choose the fonts
% \setmainfont{...}

% now a special font for listings
\defaultfontfeatures{}
\newfontfamily{\listingfont}{Latin Modern Roman}

\lstset{
  language=Rexx,
  extendedchars=true,
  frame=trbl,
  basicstyle=\listingfont
}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}
foo = 'René'
parse upper var foo bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's because of code page issues. I will be editing on multiple systems with no common code pages. If I could use ISO 8859-1 on all of them, or UTF-8 on all of them, then I would be happy to just enter the characters directly.

Comment: @shmuel Sorry, but it's rather unclear: `listings` is meant to show things verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

Using alltt with framed and upquote.

\begin{framed}
\begin{verbatim}
foo='Ren\'{e}'
bar=`Ren\'{e}`
\end{verbatim}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl, escapechar={!},linewidth=20em}

\section{Statement of problem}

\subsection{Secondary Problem}

Using upquote listings with language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl, escapechar={!}, width=20em

\begin{lstlisting}
    foo = 'Ren!\'{e}!'
    baz = `Ren!\'{e}!`
    parse upper var foo bar
\end{lstlisting}
```

\end{document}